# Iterating through a list of discord voice channels in a guild without the input of a user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I currently have:

```py
 music.find_channel()

        
        url = str(sounds[random.randint(0, 3)])
       

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        print(ctx.author.voice.channel)
        print(type(voice_channel))
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)  
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
      
        vc = ctx.voice_client

      
        vc.play(source)
```

But am attempting to remove the command aspect and have the bot, once an hour, run a find channel command that iterates through each channel in a guild and joins the first one it sees with 2 or more people in it. I cannot seem to find documentation on how I can properly list multiple voice channels in a guild without using the ctx class.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 things to do that:

1. Get all the VC channels from the guild.
2. Create a [task to run the command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) every hour.

To get the channels from the guild, you can use `bot.guild.voice_channels`. To create a task, you need to create the command under the decorator `@tasks.loop()` then start it by using `start()`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks #import tasks as well

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def joinvc():
   voice_channels = bot.get_guild(guild_id).voice_channels #replace guild_id with your guild's id.
   ##then here goes the code that you want to loop every 1 hour. 

joinvc.start() ##start the task.
```